# UnexpectedReponse in XCM when using ReportTransactStatus

Tags: xcm, xcmp, xcmv3

I'm having issues when using the `ReportTransactStatus` in my XCM message as it gives me a `UnexpectedResponse` in my origin Parachain.

How can I register the matching query in the origin, so when the destiny responds I get a more descriptive message?

This is my XCM message code:

```rust
            match send_xcm::<T::XcmSender>(
                (Parent, Junction::Parachain(mult_para_id.into())).into(),
                Xcm(vec![
                    
                    Transact {
                        origin_kind: OriginKind::Native,
                        require_weight_at_most: Weight::from_parts(1_000, 1_000),
                        call: <T as Config>::RuntimeCall::from(Call::<T>::xcm_clone_file {
                            signer,
                            energy_bank_file: new_file
                        })
                        .encode()
                        .into(),
                    },
                    ReportTransactStatus(QueryResponseInfo {
                        destination: MultiLocation {parents: 1, interior: Parachain(2000).into()},
                        query_id,
                        max_weight: Weight::from_all(0),
                    }),
                ]),
            ) {
                Ok((hash, cost)) => Self::deposit_event(Event::Success(mult_para_id)),
                Err(e) => Self::deposit_event(Event::Error(e, mult_para_id)),
            }
```

I've also tried using `SetErrorHandler` w/ `ExpectTransactStatus` as well, but I got the same results.

```rust
...
SetErrorHandler(Xcm(vec![ReportTransactStatus(QueryResponseInfo {
            destination: MultiLocation {parents: 1, interior: Parachain(2000).into()},
            query_id,
            max_weight: Weight::from_all(0),
})])),
// Transact here,
ExpectTransactStatus(MaybeErrorCode::Success),
```

The `UnexpectedResponse` error:
[image]

Deeply appreciate any help or documentation/examples to look further. Thank you

**Update:**
I've setup the `ResponseHandler` for the pallet and tight coupled with the `pallet_xcm` so I can create new queries.

But I'm now having problems when trying to call the `new_notify_query` function, because the `RuntimeCall` I'm passing as parameter is the wrong type.

Here is how I'm creating the `RuntimeCall` and how I'm calling the `new_notify_query` function.

```rust
...
let call = Call::<T>::report { query_id: 0, outcome: Default::default() };

let query_id = pallet_xcm::Pallet::<T>::new_notify_query(
    MultiLocation {parents: 1, interior: Parachain(2000).into()},
    <T as pallet::Config>::RuntimeCall::from(call),
    10u32.into(),
    Here
);
...
// The report dispatchable
#[pallet::weight((0, Pays::No))]
pub fn report(origin: OriginFor<T>, query_id: QueryId, outcome: Response) -> DispatchResult { 
    // let responder = ensure_response(<T as Config>::RuntimeOrigin::from(origin))?;
    Self::deposit_event(Event::Report(query_id, outcome));
    Ok(())
}
```

And the pallet `Config`

```rust
    #[pallet::config]
    pub trait Config: frame_system::Config + pallet_xcm::Config {
        /// The overarching event type.
        type RuntimeEvent: From<Event<Self>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::RuntimeEvent>;

        type RuntimeOrigin: From<<Self as SystemConfig>::RuntimeOrigin>
        + Into<Result<CumulusOrigin, <Self as Config>::RuntimeOrigin>>;

        /// The overarching call type; we assume sibling chains use the same type.
        type RuntimeCall: IsType<<Self as Config>::RuntimeCall> + From<Call<Self>> + Encode;


        type XcmSender: SendXcm;
        type ResponseHandler: OnResponse;
        // type PolkadotXcm: PolkadotXcm;
        type EnergyBank: EnergyBank<Self::AccountId>;
        
    }
```

The error:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have your own response handler? Check this: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/v1.4.0/polkadot/xcm/pallet-xcm/src/lib.rs#L2459, it was the default implementation.

So first, you should insert query_id into polkadot-xcm::Queries storage. Maybe using [`pallet-xcm::new_notify_query`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/v1.4.0/polkadot/xcm/pallet-xcm/src/lib.rs#L2094) which calls `do_new_query` and insert the queryId into the Queries storage.

Then, implement your response handler and config it

in `xcm_executor::Config` => `type ResponseHandler = <Yours>`

Comment: How can I insert the `query_id` into polkadot-xcm::Queries? I can't do it via extrinsics.

And about implementing my response handler, I need to implement the OnResponse trait in my XCM pallet? Then export it to my xcm_config.rs?  
Can you give me an example of a pallet using the ResponseHandler implementation? 

Thanks again for the help :)

Comment: Updating.. I've added the ResponseHandler to my pallet config, and in the runtime I used the polkadotXcm, like this: `type ResponseHandler = PolkadotXcm`
I think now I only need to register the `query_id`in the polkadot-xcm::Queries storage. How could I do that?

Comment: There is a public function [`new_notify_query`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/v1.4.0/polkadot/xcm/pallet-xcm/src/lib.rs#L2094) in pallet-xcm, which calls `do_new_query` and insert the queryId into Queries storage, you can try using it.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the help, I did a tight coupling to be able to call the function but I'm having issues with the notify parameter. I can't properly create the runtime call without getting a trait not implemented error. I've researched a lot in the repo u sent but only found references of use in a mocked environment.
I will update the question and would appreciate further help, thanks :)))

Comment: Make sure your `fn report` was a call, in `#[pallet:call] imp<T:Config> Pallet<T>{}` like [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/v1.4.0/polkadot/runtime/test-runtime/src/lib.rs#L615). I can't identify other errors.

Comment: Yes, it is. But still not working, thanks anyways :)

Comment: I found what was missing!
It was the RuntimeCall type. I updated to `type RuntimeCall: IsType<<Self as pallet_xcm::Config>::RuntimeCall> + From<Call<Self>> + Encode;` and it worked fine. 
THanks a lot for all the help :)